# WebMatrix AJAX INSERT not working

Tags: ajax, jquery, razor, webmatrix

i'm trying to add an entry into my database and update a table i have created using AJAX. I think i'm halfway there, i can send my form contents to the "partial" page, but thats where it gets stuck?

Here's my content page:

```
@{
Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";

WebSecurity.RequireAuthenticatedUser(); 

var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");

var rPropertyId = Request.QueryString["PropertyID"];

var Roominfo = "SELECT * FROM RoomInfo WHERE PropertyID=@0";
var qRoominfo = db.Query(Roominfo, rPropertyId);
}

<h2>Current Rooms</h2>

<table id="room-table" class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>Room Name</th>
    <th>Room Type</th>
    <th>Room Description</th>
</tr>
@foreach(var row in qRoominfo){
<tr>
    <td>@row.RoomName</td>
    <td>@row.RoomType</td>
    <td>@row.RoomDescription</td>
</tr>
}
</table>

<form id="add-room-form" action="@Href("~/Partials/AddRoom")">
<div class="row">
        <span class="label"><label for="title">Room Name:</label></span>
        <input type="text" name="roomname" id="roomname" size="50" />
</div>
<div class="row">
        <span class="label"><label for="title">Room Type:</label></span>
        <input type="text" name="roomtype" id="roomtype" size="50" />
</div>
<div class="row">
        <span class="label"><label for="title">Room Description:</label></span>
        <input type="text" name="roomdescription" id="roomdescription" size="50" />
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="propertyid" value="@rPropertyId" />

<button class="btn btn-success" id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">   
$(function(){
 $('#submitbutton').click(function(){             
    $.ajax({        
        type: "POST",
            url: "/Partials/AddRoom",
            data: $("#add-room-form").serialize(),
            dataType: "text/plain",                          
        success: function (data) {
            $('#room-table').html(data);
        } 
        return false;       
        });
      });                 
   });
</script>
```

and here is the partial page which "should" insert the data into the database:

```
@{
    var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");
    var sql = "INSERT INTO RoomInfo (PropertyID, RoomName, RoomType, RoomDescription, LastModified) " + 
        "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, GetDate())";
    var propertyid = Request["propertyid"];
    var roomname = Request["roomname"];
    var roomtype = Request["roomtype"];
    var roomdescription = Request["roomdescription"];
    db.Execute(sql, propertyid, roomname, roomtype, roomdescription);
}
```

In theory, it should write the info to the database, and then refresh my table, so im guessing something isn't quite right with the javascript?

Comment: Have you tried using IE developer tools? You can find out almost where the request is getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot sent the data through an ajax call is because you cannot even start the request. You are using the function to trigger when a click is made. But there will be no click event.

**Reason:** There is no button with the ID for click event. See **Click trigger issue** section below.

**Tip:** To check whether there is any Request to the server or not, you should make use of this. In every browser when you press F12 you get Developer Tools opened. Make sure you are on network tab. You will be able to check any network request made to server through there. Ajax requests are also saved there as a log, there status and everything is present there. That will be a basic but a powerfull tool to help you out in understanding how Ajax requests are made.

There are certain issues in your code too.

**Issue in the HTML:** There is an error in your code, look at the submit button. Its having code as:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"/>Submit</button>
```

Which should be:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

And then, I should change that too the following because the `type="submit"` will submit the form instead of creating an `ajax` request. I used your page in my website and just replaced the `DataBase` objects and replaced them with simple `Response` like `Response.Write()` and wrote the variables that I caught:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="submitbutton">Submit</button>
```

So the code that I changed the above one to is like this:

```
@{
  if(IsPost){
   var propertyid = "1";
   var roomname = Request["roomname"];
   var roomtype = Request["roomtype"];
   var roomdescription = Request["roomdescription"];
   var lastmodified = DateTime.Now;
   // here you will write the data to database using Database.Execute
   // Remember you should write the ajax response
   // here as a result of Response.Write()
   // However if you still want to load that page, its OK!
 }
}
```

As mentioned earlier, you were write the `propertyid` as `"'1'"` I changed that to `"1"`. But in case you want to execute as `"'1'"` its ok too.

**Click trigger issue:**

There were some other issues too. You were using:

```
$('#submitbutton').click(function(){
```

But there was no button with the ID `submitbutton`. So I changed the `id` of the button you were using there.

**What I changed in your code:**

What change I made in your code was I changed the `POST` request to `GET`. To have a look at what variables are being sent to server and what results I get. I had it easier to make use of this code as GET request was easily able to check then POST request.

If you still want to use POST request you should try to `serialize()` the form as `JSON` and send it to server. But GET will be easy.

Then I gave another field to the `$.ajax` section as:

```
data: 'roomname=' + $('#roomname').val() + 
'roomtype=' + $('#roomtype').val() + 
'roomdescription=' + $('#roomdescription').val(),
```

This will create a string of the data to be sent. And then it will be caught on that page. And I removed `if(IsPost)` too. I was able to get the result of the Response. So what you can do is to change the Response of the request and write is as:

```
$("#room-table").html(response);
```

And the table will be changed! This will remove the previous data in the table Or even whole of the table and update it with the data recieved from the Response. And then I was able to send the request to server, process the `QueryString` and then write a response and then using `$('#idofelement').html(response)` I wrote it in the specific area. You can try it as I did.

**The full code that I used was:**

One the main page I had this code:

```
 @{
  Layout = "~/_SiteLayout.cshtml";
 }

  <h2>Current Rooms</h2>

    <div class="row">
        <span class="label"><label for="title">Room Name:</label></span>
        <input type="text" name="roomname" id="roomname" size="50" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="label"><label for="title">Room Type:</label></span>
        <input type="text" name="roomtype" id="roomtype" size="50" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="label"><label for="title">Room Description:</label></span>
        <input type="text" name="roomdescription" id="roomdescription" size="50" />
    </div>
     <button class="btn btn-success" id="submitbutton" value="Submit" >Submit</button>

   <script type="text/javascript">   
    $(function(){
     $('#submitbutton').click(function(){             
        $.ajax({        
            url: '/Partials',     
            data: 'roomname=' + $('#roomname').val() + 'roomtype=' + 
            $('#roomtype').val() + "roomdescription=" + 
            $('#roomdescription').val(),
            dataType: 'text',             
            contentType: 'text/html',             
            success: function(response) {
                $("#body").html(response);
                },
            error: function(data){                 
                alert('Something went wrong');             
                }         
            });
          });                 
       });
  </script>
```

I changed the page to `partials` only and used it. Here is the content for that page.

```
@{
  var propertyid = "1";
  var roomname = Request["roomname"];
  var roomtype = Request["roomtype"];
  var roomdescription = Request["roomdescription"];
  var lastmodified = DateTime.Now;
  Response.Write("Room name: " + roomname + "<br>Room Type: " 
  + roomtype + "<br>Room Description: " + roomdescription + 
  "<br>Property: " + propertyid);
}
```

Now its upto you to use the Database variables here. Where I used Response.Write and other codes You can use the `Database` methods. And also you can add `WebSecurity` method.

Comment: are you able to send me this code? as i still can't get it to work :(

Comment: Also, i have updated my new code (both pages) above. I am still getting an error when i press the submit button.

Comment: What error? Tell me. I will update the current code so that you can use it.

Comment: Thanks, if you could paste the working code, that would be amazing

Comment: The code that I pasted what the working one. However let me paste that from A-Z

Comment: are you able to paste the full code instead of the individual parts? Would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: There you go buddy! Have a look at it. Its full code. Of first page and the other.

Comment: Hi guys, i'm still having problems with this. The data is getting inserted into my database fine, but it still needs a page request for it to show in the table. Also, it's still appending the form fields as querystring parameters on the sending page?

Answer (score 1):

The Database.Execute method requires the SQL to be executed to be passed in first. You don't appear to be passing it in at all. Also, I assume that PropertyId is an integer? If so, you should not surround it in quotes. In fact, you should try delimiting values that will be passed in via parameter at all. That's one of the benefits of using parameters. Try this:

```
@{
if(IsPost){
    var db = Database.Open("StayInFlorida");
    var sql = "INSERT INTO RoomInfo (PropertyID, RoomName, RoomType, RoomDescription, LastModified) " + 
        "VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3, GetDate())";
    var propertyid = 1;
    var roomname = Request["roomname"];
    var roomtype = Request["roomtype"];
    var roomdescription = Request["roomdescription"];
    db.Execute(sql, propertyid, roomname, roomtype, roomdescription);
}
}
```

You are hardcoding the Properytid at the moment. If you want that to be dynamic, add a hidden field to your AJAX form and set the value to `rPropertyId`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="propertyId" value="@rPropertyId" />
```

Then you can alter the 4th line in the snippet above:

```
var propertyId = Request["propertyId"];
```

Comment: excellent, i'll give that a go. So is the actual JavaScript code correct? i copied it from your example. and tried to modify it to suit my form.

Comment: i've updated the javascript, but still no luck. So to summarise, i want the sql statement on the "addroom" page to insert the contents of the form into the database, and then i want to reload the table on my main page, so it updates as soon as i click the button?